# Rewrite https Apache/Tomcat url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have working apache connected with tomcat (mod_jk), I have set two virtualhosts:

```
 myexample_8080.conf
 myexample_4430.conf
```

I want to redirect all requests from http to https and on the home page of https://myexample.com redirect to tomcat url https://myexample.com/login

This is my first rule in  myexample_8080.conf

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://myexample.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Everytime I ended up with redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/*$ https://myexample.com/info
```